# How is this service registering with listener when invalid LOCAL_LISTENER is used?

Tags: listener

I have a single instance 19c CDB with 2 PDBS, I am also running Grid Infrastructure (Oracle Restart) for ASM.

The database has LOCAL_LISTENER set to LISTENER_MYDB which is a non existent listener, and a non-existent entry in tnsname.ora

There is a listener (default name LISTENER) running on a non-default port 1641

I have create a service with srvctl for the PDB called MYDB_SRV

It shows up under lsnrctl status

```
[oracle@ +ASM ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 29-MAY-2023 13:04:01

Copyright (c) 1991, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MYSERVER)(PORT=1641)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                05-MAY-2023 23:49:25
Uptime                    23 days 13 hr. 14 min. 36 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MYSERVER)(PORT=1641)))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_DATA" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_RECO" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "MYDB_SRV" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "MYDB", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "MYDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "f4e0b1db577bb970e0530433960a8de2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "MYDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

The command completed successfully
[oracle@ +ASM ~]$
```

What I want to understand is how is that service registering with the listener when the LOCAL_LISTENER is wrong and I don't tell the service anything about the default listener on 1641?

Thanks!